# Order by alphabet and then by numbers

Tags: postgresql, order-by, sorting, natural-sort

I have records like

```
 A5
 A4
 Z1
 B2
 C7
 C1A
 C11A
 B1
 B4
```

I want them to be sorted in this manner

```
A4
A5
B1
B2
B4
C1
C11A
C7
Z1
```

using the `ORDER BY` clause.

I want them to be sorted by alphabets and then by numeric values.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417975/alphanumeric-sorting-with-postgresql

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your request:

> sorted by alphabets and then by numeric values

I assume (deriving from your sample data) you want to `ORDER BY`:

1. The first letter, treated as `text`.
2. The first number (consecutive digits), treated as `integer`.
3. The whole string to break remaining ties, treated as `text`. May or may not be needed.

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY left(col, 1)  -- 1st letter as text
     , substring(fest, '\d+')::int NULLS FIRST  -- first number in string as int
     , col  -- whole columns as cheap tiebreaker
```

[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ddd46/3)

More details:

- [Alphanumeric sorting with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11418231/939860)
- [Humanized or natural number sorting of mixed word-and-number strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12965463/939860)

Comment: Is `substring(text,text)` an undocumented variant of [`substring(string from pattern)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html)?

Comment: @JackDouglas: Yes. Both variants actually result in the same function call internally. Check the output of: `EXPLAIN VERBOSE
SELECT substring(col FROM 'FROM') AS s1, substring(col, 'COMMA') AS s2 FROM (SELECT 'foo'::text) t(col);`