# Ordering streets by their names and polysyllabic numbers in SQL query

Tags: oracle, query, order-by, oracle-sql-developer

In Oracle DB there is a table with some data:

| LAG | HNR | STREET |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00020 | 44 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 44/2 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 44/1 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 46 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 46/6 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 46/5 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 46/3 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 46/1 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 46/2 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 47 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 48 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 48/1 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 48/2 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 48A | Aachener Straße |

Please find a minimal reproducible example here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/19d625/1

Now I am trying to sort this data via the `"HNR"` in the order of `25 > 25A > 25B > 25/3` . So, the highest priority has a simple number, then goes the same number with letters (also sorted), and lastly goes the same number with a sub-number after `/` (sorted).

Using this code

```sql
SELECT F.LAG,
       F.HNR,
       F.STREET
FROM DB.F F
ORDER BY F.LAG,
         F.STREET,
         TO_NUMBER(regexp_substr(F.HNR, '[[:digit:]]{1,4}')),
         TO_CHAR(regexp_substr(F.HNR, '[[:alpha:]]{1}')),
         TO_NUMBER(regexp_substr(F.HNR, '[^/]+', 1, 2));
```

I am getting this:

| LAG | HNR | STREET |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00020 | 44/1 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 44/2 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 44 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 46/1 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 46/2 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 46/3 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 46/5 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 46/6 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 46 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 47 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 48/1 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 48/2 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 48A | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 48 | Aachener Straße |

Instead of this:

| LAG | HNR | STREET |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00020 | 44 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 44/1 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 44/2 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 46 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 46/1 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 46/2 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 46/3 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 46/5 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 46/6 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 47 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 48 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 48A | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 48/1 | Aachener Straße |
| 00020 | 48/2 | Aachener Straße |

What am I doing wrong?

I have seen [SQL: ORDER BY using a substring within a specific column… possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187828/sql-order-by-using-a-substring-within-a-specific-column-possible) and [Order by alphabet and then by numbers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52569/order-by-alphabet-and-then-by-numbers), but I did not find there anything relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would separately introduce sorting based on the *presence* of special characters in `HNR`, in addition to sorting on the bits related to those characters that you have already implemented.

You could try using `REGEXP_COUNT` for this.  Here is how you could go about it:

```
SELECT F.LAG,
       F.HNR,
       F.STREET
FROM DB.F F
ORDER BY F.LAG,
         F.STREET,
         TO_NUMBER(regexp_substr(F.HNR, '[[:digit:]]{1,4}')),
         regexp_count(F.HNR, '[/]'),  -- numbers with strokes follow those without strokes
         regexp_count(F.HNR, '[[:alpha:]]'),  -- no-letter numbers first
         TO_CHAR(regexp_substr(F.HNR, '[[:alpha:]]{1}')),
         TO_NUMBER(regexp_substr(F.HNR, '[^/]+', 1, 2));
```

The two additional sorting criteria I added above will result in the following:

| HNR | regexp_count(HNR, '[/]') | regexp_count(HNR, '[[:alpha:]]') |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 48 | 0 | 0 |
| 48A | 0 | 1 |
| 48/1 | 1 | 0 |

As you can see, using them in that specific order will produce the desired sorting order for HNR.

See live demo of this solution [at SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c6d0d6/1), [at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=70cd7a7c95d2224634de9ff24f7480f1).

Answer (score 2):

## PostgreSQL

With PostgreSQL you can do this,

```
SELECT x
FROM ( VALUES ('25'), ('25A'), ('25B'), ('25/3') ) AS t(x)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL regexp_matches(x, '(\d+)(?:(\w+)|(?:\/(\d+)))?')
  AS re(m)
ORDER BY m[1], m[3] NULLS FIRST, m[2] NULLS FIRST;
```

The key here is

```
CROSS JOIN LATERAL regexp_matches(x, '(\d+)(?:(\w+)|(?:\/(\d+)))?')
  AS re(m)
```

That returns an ARRAY with your matches,

```
  x   |       m        
------+----------------
 25   | {25,NULL,NULL}
 25A  | {25,A,NULL}
 25B  | {25,B,NULL}
 25/3 | {25,NULL,3}
```

We just want to order

- by the numbers first so that's `m[1]`
- by the third column which is null in `{ 25, 25A, 25B }`. So bump those to the top, but for the `25/3` and `25/4` order ASC (the default)
- and then lastly, order by the second column in ASC order with NULLs at the top.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer looks promising and really advanced for me. I do not understand yet how to adapt it to real fields in my Oracle DB instead of `VALUES`.

Comment: That's a nice feature. There's nothing like that in Oracle, though.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do it? (I generated my own test data to make it easier to confirm that `'4'` comes before `'44'` etc.)

```
with street_numbers (hnr) as
     ( select n1.column_value||n2.column_value
       from   table(sys.ku$_vcnt('4','40','44')) n1
              cross join table(sys.ku$_vcnt('', 'A','B','/1','/11')) n2 )
select hnr
from   street_numbers
order by
       regexp_substr(hnr,'^\d+')
     , replace(hnr,'/',chr(123));
```

which gives:

```
HNR
-----
4
4A
4B
4/1
4/11
40
40A
40B
40/1
40/11
44
44A
44B
44/1
44/11
```

The idea is to sort by the leading numeric first, so 4 comes before 5 etc, then by the whole string but changing any `/` to an arbitrary character above `z`.